# plotting larger scale network topology efficiently in python

Tags: python, plot, igraph, networkx

I'm now have a larger scale network with node and link information, and I want to plot the network topology in python. I have tried using matplotlib to plot each link in for loop, but it seems very time-consuming. How can I plot the whole network in short time? I have attached sample node information and link information here, and they are both saved as .csv file. What I want to do is visualizing the network as the last picture.

[image: node information]

[image: link information]

[image: network]

Comment: Could you please give us a bit more information? How is your network stored? For example, do you have a list of nodes and list of edges between them, or are you using a library like networkx or igraph (as your tags suggest)?

Comment: @JohannesWachs I have modified the question above (added node and link information description). Actually, I'm now developing GUI (using PyQt5) in python to visualize network (with zoom in and zoom out function), so network plotting must be efficient enough. Now, I have no idea about how do these two libraries work and if they can help me. Thanks.